# Add two or more columns to one with sum

Tags: r

An input data structure

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), name = c(0,1,0) col = c(1,1,0), another = c(1,2,0))
```

What kind of command can add two (or more) columns and create a new one where the sum is grearter than one add 1?

Here an example result, add the columns with names name and col from df and create a new column with the name combine:

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), combine = c(1,1,0), another = c(1,2,0))
```

Comment: Try `as.integer(rowSums(d1[c('name', 'col')]) > 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `rowSums`.

```
c.col <- c("name", "col")
res <- data.frame(combine=+(rowSums(d[c.col]) > 0), d[!names(d) %in% c.col])
res
#   combine id another
# 1       1  1       1
# 2       1  2       2
# 3       0  3       0

res <- res[c(2, 1, 3)]  ## order columns if needed
#   id combine another
# 1  1       1       1
# 2  2       1       2
# 3  3       0       0
```

---

*Data:*

```
d <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3), name = c(0, 1, 0), col = c(1, 
1, 0), another = c(1, 2, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: thank you, is it possible to make it with the names of the columns and not with the place in the dataframe?